# Macro Needed To Bulk Edit/Style Large Microsoft Word Document

Tags: vba, ms-word

Looking to take raw text, and do the following...

a) set all text to a certain font

b) delete extra spaces and tabs

c) organize lists with certain titles, identically (i.e. multiple shopping lists should look the same across the entire document).

I know this is likely possible via a simple macro, but my programming knowledge + Google-fu has come up empty on this.

Comment: Please share what you have tried from your side.

Comment: step a) is easy ... select all text (ctrl-a) and choose font setting  ...... step b) .. what is an extra space? what is an extra tab?

Comment: The closest I have come to anything, is the use of wild cards, via find and replace. It looks like this should work, but I want a solution that is 1 script, to avoid confusion/potential formatting issues. I'm working with a document that is 100+ pages. To clarify, for step c, script would find 'shopping list', and keep putting each line of following text directly under it, until the script finds 'to do', and then do the same thing with that. After next empty line is found, it would then insert a page break. This should be like ~10 lines of code, I just can't seem to find anything.